# Populating a tuple with elements in another tuple

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, tuples

In a template like below, how can I populate a tuple from elements within another more complex tuple?

```
template<typename... Ts>
struct foo {
  std::tuple<std::vector<Ts>...> tuple;

  foo() {
    //populate tuple somehow
    //assume that no vector is empty
  }

  void func() {
    std::tuple<Ts...> back_tuple; // = ...
    //want to populate with the last elements ".back()" of each vector
    //how?
  }
};
```

I can't find any push_back mechanism for tuples, so I'm not sure how to use template looping tricks to do this. Also, I can't find any initializer_list like template for varying types to collect my values to then pass into the new tuple. Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
std::tuple<std::vector<Ts>...> t;

template <int...> struct Indices {};
template <bool> struct BoolType {};

template <int ...I>
std::tuple<Ts...> back_tuple_aux(BoolType<true>, Indices<I...>)
{
    return std::make_tuple(std::get<I>(t).back()...);  // !!
}

template <int ...I>
std::tuple<Ts...> back_tuple_aux(BoolType<false>, Indices<I...>)
{
    return back_tuple_aux(BoolType<sizeof...(I) + 1 == sizeof...(Ts)>(),
                          Indices<I..., sizeof...(I)>());
};

std::tuple<Ts...> back_tuple()
{
    return back_tuple_aux(BoolType<0 == sizeof...(Ts)>(), Indices<>());
}
```

(The magic happens in the line marked `!!`.)